# Create database link to connect another PC in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, fragment

On Oracle/SQLDeveloper I use

```
CONNECT TO username IDENTIFIED BY p123
```

for distributing project but in SQL Server I can't do this.

I mean one PC for example `PC1` is a global table on this pc,  and I want others PC to be able to access this `PC1` such as fragment and distribute, I try it in SQL developer successfully but I can't this in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Check your network settings. Makes sure the ports that need to be exposed are exposed. Consider reviewing the SQL Distributed Server documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/?view=sql-server-ver15

This looks like a good place to start. Your English is good, keep practicing!

I would have left a comment but I don't have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

On the remote machine, make sure the ports are opened in the Firewall config and TCP is enabled:
[Microsoft SQL Server ports](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Docs-v1.1.2/GUID-CF5C89EA-0918-4002-8391-80CBEDE0BB5E)

Reference: [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
USE [master]  
GO  
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver   
    @server = N'SRVR002\ACCTG',   
    @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' ;  
GO
```

Execute the following code to configure the linked server to use the domain credentials of the login that is using the linked server.

```sql
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin   
    @rmtsrvname = N'SRVR002\ACCTG',   
    @locallogin = NULL ,   
    @useself = N'True' ;  
GO
```

Add a password login:
Reference: [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedsrvlogin-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
    @rmtsrvname = 'SRVR002\ACCTG',
    @useself = 'false',
    --@locallogin = 'MACHINENAME\windowsLogin' -- Restrict the connection to a local login
    @rmtuser = 'User',
    @rmtpassword = 'Password'
```

Accessing the linked server:

```sql
SELECT name FROM [SRVR002\ACCTG].master.sys.databases ;  
GO
```

You can also setup remote server links via the MSSQL Management Studio GUI.

Here's a more detailed reference with images on how to do it via MSSQL Management Studio
[Querying remote data sources in sql server](https://www.sqlshack.com/querying-remote-data-sources-in-sql-server/)

To execute remote queries you will have to set **rpc out** to true.

You can also create linked server connections on the fly via [OPENDATASOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/opendatasource-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), but this requires you to set this config:

```sql
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: Sir, it is no clear for me , please I need help, my problem is; I have 2 pc in a different place and i want to create a link server between them to use some database in remote pc from pc1??